# How do I create ordinal value from continuous value if they fall per 2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I want to create ordinal value from continuous value, how can I split per 2? I can use cut function to create 2 bins or 50 bins if I had 100 data and are incremental. If I had random dataset, how can I create ordinal value per 2 for instance? For example if I have a columns with `[1,2,3,2,2,4,5,10,15,20]` and I want to create ordinal per 5 degree, thr result would look like `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3]`.  This is what I would use if I want to create bucket of 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'normal': np.random.normal(10, 3, 1000),
    'chi': np.random.chisquare(4, 1000)
})

pd.cut(df['normal'], 2)
```

Comment: The provided example doesn't really make sense. With a step of 5 there is no reason why 10 and 15 should be in the same bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could use a simple floor division (`//` or [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.floordiv.html)):

If you want interval of the kind `[0, 5), [5, 10), [10, 15)...` (right excluded) use `x//N+1`:

```
N = 5
df['x//N+1'] = df['col'].floordiv(N).add(1)
```

For `(0, 5], (5, 10], (10, 15]...` (left excluded, right included), use (`(x-1)//N+1`):

```
df['(x-1)//N+1'] = df['col'].sub(1).floordiv(N).add(1)
```

Example:

```
    col  x//N+1  (x-1)//N+1
0     0       1           0
1     1       1           1
2     2       1           1
3     3       1           1
4     2       1           1
5     2       1           1
6     4       1           1
7     5       2           1
8    10       3           2
9    15       4           3
10   20       5           4
```

Other example:

```
df['bin'] = df['normal']//N+1

        normal       chi  bin
0    13.994760  8.965983  3.0
1    12.145837  2.979170  3.0
2     5.363799  7.419285  2.0
3     9.974848  5.427561  2.0
4    11.864008  4.008033  3.0
..         ...       ...  ...
995   6.956982  4.982800  2.0
996   9.004517  0.593757  2.0
997  14.322092  7.667032  3.0
998   8.829346  6.702100  2.0
999  11.927352  6.365029  3.0

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do:

```
N = 2
a = np.floor(df['normal'].min())
b = np.ceil(df['normal'].max())
bins = np.arange(a, b + N - (b % N) + 1, N)

out = pd.cut(df['normal'], bins)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
0      (12.0, 14.0]
1      (12.0, 14.0]
2        (4.0, 6.0]
3       (8.0, 10.0]
4      (10.0, 12.0]
           ...     
995      (6.0, 8.0]
996     (8.0, 10.0]
997    (14.0, 16.0]
998     (8.0, 10.0]
999    (10.0, 12.0]
Name: normal, Length: 1000, dtype: category
Categories (10, interval[float64, right]): [(0.0, 2.0] < (2.0, 4.0] < (4.0, 6.0] < (6.0, 8.0] < ... <
                                            (12.0, 14.0] < (14.0, 16.0] < (16.0, 18.0] <
                                            (18.0, 20.0]]
```